# Formik load entire formvalues on dropdownchange

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I am new to formik and could not figure out a way to how to make an API call on dropdown change and reassign the new values to the form.

I've the below formik form with a dropdown filled with years. Can someone help me how to call the searchlogs on dropdown/year change and refill the form with the new values.

```
    type IVFModel = {
    LogType: LogType;
    Period: string;
    AsstInitials: string;
    SignedAt: Date | string;
    Payload: IIVFPayload;
};

const years = Array.from({ length: (2023 - (new Date().getFullYear()) + 2) }, (_, i) => (2023 + i).toString());

const Influenza = () => {
    const [ivfModel, setIVFModel] = useState<IVFModel>(initialValues);    

    useEffect(() => {
      searchLogs();
    }, []);


    
    const searchLogs = async () => {
        const postdata: ILogFind = {
          LogType: initialValues.LogType,
          Period: initialValues.Period,            
        };
        const { data } = await axios.post<ILogData[]>("/api/log/find", postdata);

        if (data.length > 0) {
            const ivfRecord = data[0];
            const ivfM: IVFModel = {
                LogType: ivfRecord.LogType,
                Period: ivfRecord.Period!,
                AsstInitials: ivfRecord.AsstInitials,
                SignedAt: new Date(ivfRecord.SignedAt),
                Payload: JSON.parse(ivfRecord.Payload!) as IIVFPayload
            };
            setIVFModel(ivfM);
        }
    };

    const exportToPdf = async () => {
        //download pdf
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = async (values: IVFModel, { setErrors, setSubmitting, setStatus }: FormikHelpers<IVFModel>) => {
        //submit call here
        setSubmitting(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>            
            <Formik onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} initialValues={ivfModel} validationSchema={validationSchema} enableReinitialize>
                {({ values, errors, touched, isSubmitting, status, dirty, handleBlur, handleSubmit, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched }) => {                    
                    return (
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "2rem" }}>                                
                                <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "10px", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                                    <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: '1rem', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                        <div>
                                            <Dropdown options={fillOptions(years)} search selection value={values.Period}
                                                onChange={(e, { value }) => { setFieldValue("Period", value); }} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                                            <div>Last saved by:&nbsp;</div>
                                            <div className="signature-text">{ivfModel.AsstInitials ?? ""}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                                            <div>Last saved on:&nbsp;</div>
                                            <div className="signature-text">{ivfModel.SignedAt.toLocaleString() ?? ""}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                                            <div><Button type="button" primary onClick={exportToPdf}>Export to PDF</Button></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    );
                }}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
};

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({

});

const initialValues: IVFModel = {
    LogType: LogType.Influenza,
    Period: new Date().getFullYear().toString(),
    AsstInitials: "",
    SignedAt: "",
    Payload: emptyIVFPayload
};

export default Influenza;
```